# Prove this result about power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I have to prove this result:

> If $P$ be the power set, and $B$ and $C$ are two sets, then if $B \subseteq C$ prove that $P(B) \subseteq P(C)$.

Now, it seems *obvious* to me that since all the elements of B are in C, all possible combinations of the elements of C must include those that of B. But other than this straightforward argument, I'm at a loss to see what kind of proof can be given for statements like these.

Can anyone suggest something more "proper"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X\in P(B)\implies X\subset B$ by definition of $P(B)$; by hypothesis, $B\subset C$, so $X\subset C$ and therefore $X\in P(C)$ again by definition of $P(C)$. We have shown that $B\subset C$ implies $P(B)\subset P(C)$.

In other words--you're right, it *is* obvious, but if you have to write something, just write the obvious. :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, at the end of the day everything is obvious, but I wanted something more systematic. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not much more than your "obvious" argument is needed.

To prove that $\mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(C)$ you need to take an arbitrary $A\in\mathcal P(B)$ and show that this $A$ is in $\mathcal P(C)$.

But $A\in\mathcal P(B)$ means neither more nor less than $A\subseteq B$, and so we have $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$. Therefore $A\subseteq C$, which is the same as saying $A\in\mathcal P(C)$, which was what we had to prove.